# How to use `grep` as to choose lines with column > 1?

Tags: linux, grep

I get results like below from a pipeline in linux:

```
1 test1
1 test2
2 test3
1 test4
3 test5
1 test6
1 test7
```

How can I use grep to retrieve only the lines where the first column is > 1?

Comment: I edited out the reference to SQL in the title. In two recent questions you've asked about grep in a SQL context, then not shown any sql in the question. Which leads my to ask "Are you filtering the results of an SQL query with grep?" I mean, why? SQL is a sophisticated filtering language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "^" char, it marks the beginning of a line

-v will not include lines starting with 1

include the extra space, so it will exclude lines like "1 asd" but not "12 asd"

```
grep -v "^1 "
```

Comment: What's 23456789 in this example?

Comment: it means any of this characters, so any digit char is valid

Comment: ok, but then this doesn't really support the column > 1 requirement

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `grep` for this. Try `awk` instead:

```
 <pipeline> | awk '$1>1 {print $0}'
```

Comment: I can't use awk, it has to be one of the standard tools

Comment: awk is standard. it's available on every *nix

Comment: awk is a 'standard tool', in that it's part of the POSIX standard and should be present on any UNIX-like system which you'd expect to find grep. grep only deals with strings characters, not numbers, and so doesn't have a concept of 'greater than'.

Comment: I get that, but for this task I was asked not to use it.

Comment: @dmckee: beautiful solution. You can shorten the awk script to '$1>1' -- the default is to print out the line.

Comment: You know, I kind of picked up awk as I went along, and never knew ther *was* a default action. You learn something every day.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -v "^1"
```

- -v selects non-matching lines
- ^ is the start of a line

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this solution does not filter out lines starting with multi-digit numbers. Adding a space after the 1 solves the problem:

```
grep -v "^1 "
```

Comment: @goe, @Hai Vu: Thanks for pointing out the problem with multi-digit numbers. I edited the answer to account for it.